# "Questions that may already have your answer" bug on first click

Tags: bug, status-completed, related-questions

Does anyone else experience this?

1) Click Ask Question

2) Type question **but** stop typing halfway

3) The 'Questions that may already have your answer" generates

4) Finish typing question

6) Without clicking anywhere or pressing tab, click one of the 'related questions'.

I find that it refreshes and a link you thought you have clicked may not be there when the 'new results' load

---

I've finally figured it out, I've been losing the links and have to find which word combination the (ajax?) questions loaded to find what I had seen.. Would you consider this an issue?

Comment: I am not clear what happened when you did that. To me, it opened a new tab containing the question I clicked upon.

Comment: If related questions load and you type more, and the updated related questions do not load: once you go to click on an 'old' link, the new links refresh and the link you wanted is gone. That's what happens to me

Comment: This bug becomes more obvious with the following steps: (Using Firefox) 1. type a title until the list appears; 2. Scroll down in the list - the title field keeps the focus; 3. try to click on a link -> you'll miss it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with the next build if you try and click on a link (that is your mouse is *over* a suggested question link), we won't load new suggestions when the title box loses focus (which is one of the triggers for loading new suggestions).