# The "Questions that may already have your answer" list is not cleared after a question draft is discarded

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, related-questions

When the draft of a question is discarded, the list of questions which could contain the answer is not removed: After the window asking confirmation for discarding the draft is show, the page refreshes, but the list of questions is still there.

[image: screenshot demonstrating the question list and empty question textarea]

Comment: I think this stems from the same bug: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148650/questions-that-may-already-have-your-answer-bug-on-first-click#comment427387_148650

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those suggestions will be dismissed when you discard a draft starting with the next build.